# Ignoring Sentry Errors

Tags: javascript, angular, security, sentry

I want to ignore sentry errors coming from third party libs in my application, so I added allowUrls: ['{{domain name}}'], but it does not seem to be ignoring the errors. We also have denyUrls in the config, ex: denyUrls: [ 'gtm.js', 'fbevents.js']. Is it because we have both deny and allow url config, that sentry is not honouring allowUrls config.

Answer (score 0):

Their developer said:

> allowUrls only checks the URLs of the stack frames. Since this error
> doesn't have a stack trace, we can't check against it.

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/7047